# Should I use JQuery dialog to display/submit form elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit, jquery-ui-dialog

I work on the system where JQuery dialog is used as a main tool to display text/elements in dialog box. I need to display form with some elements that should be validated. I like to use HTML5 validation with pattern. In order to use that I need to trigger form submit. I'm wondering how that can be triggered with JQuery dialog Save/Submit button?

Here is example of my code:

```js
$(".add").on('click', addRecord);

function addRecord() {
  var form = $('<form name="frm_save" id="frm_save" autocomplete="off"></form>');
  var subject = $('<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="title">Title:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_title" id="frm_title"></div>').attr({
    pattern: "[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z '.,-:()]{0,50}$",
    title: "Allowed charachters: A-Za-z .,-():",
    maxlength: 50,
    required: true,
    placeholder: "Enter Title"
  });
  form.append(subject);
  displayForm(form, 'Add Record');
}

function saveRecord() {
  //Here I want to preventDefault() and run some checks before form gets submited.
  console.log('Submit');
}

function displayForm(msg, msgTitle, minH, width) {
  if (msgTitle == undefined) msgTitle = 'System Message';
  if (minH == undefined) minH = 100;
  if (width == undefined) width = 435;

  if (!$("#message-dialog").length) $("<div id='message-dialog'></div>").appendTo("body");

  $("#message-dialog").html(msg);
  $("#message-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    title: msgTitle,
    minHeight: minH,
    width: width,
    modal: true,
    position: {
      my: "center",
      at: "center",
      of: window
    },
    draggable: false,
    buttons: [{
        text: "Submit",
        class: "btn btn-primary",
        id: "btn_submit",
        click: function() {
          saveRecord(this);
        }
      },
      {
        text: "Close",
        class: "btn btn-primary",
        click: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    ]
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="add">Add</button>
```

Comment: `$('form').submit()` or click `<submit type='submit'>` or `<button>Submit</button>` or while `focus` is on `<form>` ENTER/RETURN key. All of theses ways to submit a form needs a `<form>` of course. Then there's `$.axax()` as well.

Comment: @zer00ne If I want to do form submit in `saveRecord()` function how html5 validation can be triggered?

Comment: Add `required` attribute to each form control you want validated. That's default messages, if you want to have serious validation use a plugin , there's a ton of them.

Comment: And how to trigger that? In saveRecord() function.

Comment: It gets triggered when submit, if your pattern catches something from an input with `required` the submit event is canceled and the message pops up. So `saveRecord()` isn't really needed unless you are not really sending data to a server.

Comment: @zer00ne In case if I use ajax to submit form how that can triggered then?

Comment: Just posted an answer, if you use ajax place it within `saveRecord()` and then use `saveRecord()` as an event handler for the submit event.

Answer (score 0):

Simply having a `<form>` and form controls with the `[required]` attribute already covers basic validation (like an empty field). By adding constraints by `[type]` or `[pattern]` the [constraint validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) will cover it 99% of the time. The following demo submits to a live test server, the iframe will display the server response. The input value is intentionally invalid so submit the form as is to test validation.

```html
<form id='main' action='https://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php' method='post' target='response'>
  <input id='test' name='test' type='email' value='byte2me.com' required><input type='submit'>
</form>
<iframe name='response'></iframe>
```